# FIR filtering a limited subband of a signal

Tags: finite-impulse-response, downsampling, filter-bank, polyphase

I have a full band audio signal (sampled at 48000Hz) and I want to process only the low frequencies with an FIR filter.

The maximum frequency that I need to process with the FIR is 3000Hz, i.e., an eighth of the Nyquist frequency of my original signal.

Computational cost of the final processing is critical to my application.

My naive approach was to split the signal in 2 using a basic Linkwitz-Riley crossover filter, to decimate the LF component by a factor 8, process it with my FIR, then upsample with a linear phase anti-imaging filter and finally recombine it with the HP component (delayed by my FIR delay).

I'm reading into polyphase FIR filtering and Perfect-Reconstruction filter banks and wondering if that approach would be more efficient than the one I have been using so-far, but I'm completely new to polyphase filtering/filter banks and couldn't really figure out if they apply to what I'm trying to do.

What would be the best approach here? I don't care about the phase/group delay of the reconstructed signal but I do care about any audio artefacts that could appear (pre/post ringing, bad recombination of the 2 components etc.)

Comment: If "computational cost" is the goal here and than details matter a lot. What specific processing do you need to apply, what happens to the other bands, why do you need to upsample again in the first place, what noise level and/or artefacts can you tolerate, etc ?

Comment: The processing is a arbitrary phase filter in the LF component. The other band is simply delayed and then both are summed for reconstruction. The final signal needs to be a full-band audio signal which is why I need to upsample again (otherwise I can't sum the LF and HF back together). I can tolerate artefacts that are below 96dB, for pre-ringing it's hard to objectify what my audible threshold is so ive mostly been evaluating it with listening sessions

Comment: My thought would be you don’t actually need a filter bank, you need a polyphase FIR filter since you are only interested in processing one band. resample() in Matlab does this. Causal, non-trivial FIRs have unavoidable ringing, but causal IIRs will have phase noise which may result in bad reconstruction. There are polyphase IIR filters, but designing these is more difficult. There are tradeoffs that you will likely have to explore in depth to see what works.